# Java - Custom paint declaration performance

Tags: java, performance, swing, graphics2d

Quick yes, no, or it doesn't really matter:

I'm overriding the paint method for an abstract button and I'm wondering if doing

```
GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, color1, 0, h, color2);
RoundRectangle2D r = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, w, h, w/5, h/5);
```

and similar methods are going to affect performance vs

```
GradientPaint gp;
RoundRectangle2D r;
```

outside paint and then

```
gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, color1, 0, h, color2);
r = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, w, h, w/5, h/5);
```

inside the paint method

Comment: You should be overriding paintComponent() not paint().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for the most maintainable solution until you measure problems :-)

Every "optimization" requires additional logic (aka: LOC). Each additional line has a - difficult to predict - price in maintenance. My general rule it not add uncalculatable costs.

BTW: you can't do your first option anyway, gradients are immutable - so you have to recreate each time the size has changed.

Comment: @Jeremy: she is the queen of the Nile and of Swing.

Answer (score 4):

How's it going Jeremy?

Not what you're asking, but quickest of all would likely be to do the drawing once in a BufferedImage, and then display the BufferedImage in the paint (or perhaps better paintComponent) method.

Comment: +1 Not just quicker than me, but remembered to comment on `paintComponent` (and mentioned a BI!).

Comment: Both great suggestions. Not to be nit picky, but it sounds like you told me more proper ways to paint, and didn't actually answer the performance question =x

Comment: Both comments implicitly suggested that these proper ways to paint *were* more efficient than instantiating GPs & RRs in a loop.  Though perhaps we could have been more explicit on the matter.  ;)

Comment: And in relation to 'size change' and using a `BufferedImage`. A BI is how I'd normally do custom rendering.  It is just necessary to check the size within paint, and if different to component size, generate a new one (same principle with the raw paint constructs mentioned in my answer).

Comment: The answer to your direct question is: it would seem that it should be more efficient to create the objects once (as AT states), but it really depends on the JVM. The JVM is often smart enough to optimize these sorts of things, but this is not part of the spec and may be JVM dependent. Fastest though still would be to use a BufferedImage.

Answer (score 4):

Instantiate them once or when necessary (e.g. size change) rather than many times.

Comment: 1+ regarding the size change suggestion.